Understanding how to evaluate the integral causal-effect expression
I have this expression
$$
p( Y \mid \text{do}(Z=z)) = 
\int_{B, S, W, X} dBdSdWdX \ \ P(B | S) P(W | B, S) P(X | B, S, Z=z)  \left[ \int_{Z'} dZ' P(Z'| B,S,W) P(Y | B, S, W, X, Z') P(S) \right] 
$$
which represents the causal effect on $Y$ from making an intervention on $Z$ in the causal graph $\mathcal{G}$ which is part of a structural causal model.
This was found through the ID algorithm for those who are familiar with the literature.
Problem is now, I am not quite sure what this result means, in particular the inner integral. What does $Z'$ represent here? How do I evaluate this? Say that the intervention domain for my $Z$ variable is $[-2,2]$ and I intervene on $Z=1$, does this expression mean that I integrate the inner integral over the whole domain $[-2,2]$ except $Z=1$?
Thanks

I believe the result is a sequential application of the conditional front-door criterion and the backdoor criterion, from the do-calculus, to achieve the identification of $p(Y\mid\text{do}(Z=z))$ (not the expected value), given a latent confounder between $Z$ and $Y$.
It seems like $X$ is a mediator of the effect of $Z$ on $Y$ satisfying some graphical conditions to be leveraged for the identication of $p(Y\mid\text{do}(Z=z), W, B, S)$ via the front-door criterion (conditional on $W,B,S$) as:
$$\begin{aligned}
& p(Y\mid\text{do}(Z=z), W, B, S)\\
&\, = \int \text{d}X\, p(X\mid Z=z,B,S) \int \text{d}Z'\, p(Z'\mid W,B,S)\, p(Y\mid X, Z',W,B,S)
\end{aligned}
$$
The final result is obtained via marginalization of non-$Z$-descendants (confounders) $W,B,S$, as:
$$\begin{aligned}
& p(Y\mid\text{do}(Z=z))\\
&\, = \iiint \text{d}W\,\text{d}B\,\text{d}S\, p(W\mid B,S)\, p(B\mid S)\,p(S)\,  p(Y\mid\text{do}(Z=z), W, B, S)
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus, the inner-most integral $\int \text{d}Z'p(Z'\mid W,B,S)\cdots $ should be done in the whole support of $Z$: all possible values for the intervention, including the value to evaluate $z$.

Thanks for this excellent answer, very helpful (I have also updated the question to remove the expectation).
Perhaps if you will allow me probe you a bit further then; should I want to approximate this with Monte-carlo integration (essentially just sampling it a lot of times to get an estimate of aforementioned expectation) then I take lots of samples from the joint, my intervention, and plus it all in, eventually taking the average over all samples?
